# SharePoint server REST: Find folder by attribute

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am developing an integration between several systems and in one point I have to find the files inside a folder using the SharePoint REST API. The data I have to look for the folder is the List were it is and an attribute named "Código de material". I am by no means a SharePoint expert. So, I am sorry beforehand for the terms mistakes.

[image: my folder screenshot]

I have been trying with a few REST method but to no avail. For example:

```
https://sharepointserver.com/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyListName')/items?$filter=C%C3%B3digo%20de%20Material=%27000000000000401426%27
```

returns this error message

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="es-ES">La expresión "Código de Material='000000000000401426'" no es válida.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

What would be the correct way to filter a list by a given folder attribute?

FWIW I am using Java but the question is about the REST call really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
https://sharepointserver.com/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyListName')/items?$filter=C_x00f3_digo_x0020_de_x0020_Mate%20eq%20%27000000000000401426%27
```

You need to use internal column name in the query.